# Launching Android intents from browser with extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

I am able to launch an Android intent in webview this way:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=...;end">Do something</a>
```

But I'm struggling to replicate this for intents with the "has extras" bit. For instance, how do I turn this:

```
final Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent1.setType("text/plain");
intent1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "AAA");
startActivity(intent1);
```

Into a one line uri so that it has the "putExtra" part? So far I've only got as far as below and am struggling to find examples that do this.

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND;type=text/plain;end">Send something</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a work through JS:

**Java:**

```
    WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
    {
       @JavascriptInterface           // For API 17+
       public void performClick(String strl)
       {
          final Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          intent1.setType("text/plain");
          intent1.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, strl);
          startActivity(intent1);
       }
    }, "ok");
```

**HTML:**

```
<button type="button" value="someValue" onclick="ok.performClick(this.value);">OK</button>
```

More details and examples here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

Comment: I was hoping there's a way to avoid having to fiddle with the Java code. But it actually turned out simpler than expected and works like a charm. Thanks!